# Packet analysis for network printing, bad label printing

Tags: networking, printing, wireshark

We have a printer here, that should print labels on wood, however, some of the labels appear to have their data either cut off halfway (as in, the current job gets updated by the next one), so the data is incomplete, or there is something wrong with the data being transmitted to the printer and it's printing half labels.

I am a bit new to network printing and printing with "asynchronous" printers. I have already asked the seller, how to troubleshoot this; he told me to check the script that is in the job, but the script only calls the IP, nothing else.

Here is the Picture as well as the link for the wireshark capture, as at a glance it seems normal, but I have not much experience in packets to notice if something is wrong (collisions, etc.). They also seem to be out of order; that happens when the label is cut off (left half). So the sequence could be 15, 14, 13 (cut off), 13, 13, 12, 10,... There is no real pattern.

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0s6R.jpg)

Wireshark file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bchsnoxr68jgxu/ws1.pcapng?dl=0

Python script: https://www.dropbox.com/s/532xqtv8ee0qgzz/REA.py?dl=0

[image: Image of actions on printer]

Comment: A lot of information is missing. When you say 'it only calls the IP', what does that mean? `curl`? `nc`? Would a small wait period (`sleep 1`) solve the problem? Is there a way, from the scripting side, to determine whether a print is ready?  Can you add the relevant part of the script to the question? Does the printing of the previous label stop when you send a new label to the printer?

Comment: Sleep would not really work, as this is a production printer, and too much "sleep" would really delay it. There is a sleep(1) in the script already, if data is null. I can't test it extensively, as that would require to stop production, and that is the real problem here, but I also can not find an error with my current knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being able to test is a serious problem if you are going to change things. Your picture for the print code is not sufficient; you need to to look further.
In general, it is better to post the code here than to put it on dropbox. Your dropbox files will expire at some time, and then the links you put in this question are suddenly dead. In the future, someone stumbling on this question will be left puzzled because information is missing.

This may not be the answer to your problem, but it should give you some idea whee to look.

After these preliminaries: The pyhon-code you provided has a number of routines. Most of the code will simply throw XML-code to your printer. These can be found back in you pcap file.

Things you need to know from the rea-module on dropbox:

```
def STARTJOB(ip):
    xml = '<REA-JET><REA-PI version="3.3"><Command name="STARTJOB" id="0"><Data /></Command></REA-PI></REA-JET>'
    return ExecuteCommand(ip,xml)

def STOPJOB(ip):
    xml = '<REA-JET><REA-PI version="3.3"><Command name="STOPJOB" id="0"><Data /></Command></REA-PI></REA-JET>'
    return ExecuteCommand(ip,xml)
```

The `ExecuteCommand` sends the data to the printer. All stuff is sent in clear text.  So you can see the exact sequence of calls in your pcap file.

When I go through the pcap, I see that every job is stopped explicitly. In the hex-dumb of the packets, you can see the packets with `Command name="STOPJOB"` every time before a `Command name="STARTJOB"`. The sequence seems to be setjob, startjob, stopjob.

My quess is that the stopjob is sent before the label is completely printed, thus aborting the print. But to be sure, you must do some testing.

So, there is the option to make a sleep just before the stopjob, which, as you said, make production a second per label print slower. The other option is to check if the print is ready and only sleep if the print is not completed.

The last option means that you must be able to retrieve the job status from the printer. That might be done with the

```
def Feedback(data):
    # Get feedback from the controller, so we can display it in the UI
    # Two parameters are returned, the status code and the status message
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET1
    root = ET1.fromstring(data)
    try:
        code = root.find('REA-PI/Status/Code').text  
    except:
        code = ''
    try:
        message = root.find('REA-PI/Status/Message').text
        if message == None:
            message = ''
    except:
        message = ''

    return code, message
```

But I do not know the return codes and the messages their meaning. The meaning is in `REA-PI/Status/Code`.